# Convert multiple .mp3 files to .wav files in a folder using ffmpeg

Tags: mac, audio, ffmpeg, conversion

I have multiple folders containing a lot of .mp3 files and I wanted to know how to convert those .mp3 files in those folders to .wav files, preferably using ffmpeg but isn't necessary.

I would like to be able to do it through an automated script so I don't have to convert 1200 .mp3's by "hand".

Comment: Research the `find` command.